# How to properly write an interactive shell program which can exploit bash's autocompletion mechanism

Tags: bash, autocomplete, interactive, interactive-shell

(Please, help me adjust title and tags.)

When I run `connmanctl` I get a different prompt,

```
enrico:~$ connmanctl
connmanctl>
```

and different commands are available, like `services`, `technologies`, `connect`, ...

I'd like to know how this thing works.

I know that, in general, changing the prompt can be just a matter of changing the variable `PS1`. However this thing alone (read "the command `connmanctl` changes `PS1` and returns) wouldn't have any effect at all on the functionalities of the commands line (I would still be in the same `bash` process).

Indeed, the fact that the available commands are changed, looks to me like the proof that `connmanctl` is running all the time the prompt is `connmanctl>`, and that, upon running `connmanctl`, a `while` loop is entered with a `read` statement in it, followed by a bunch of commands which process the the input.

In this latter scenario that I imagine, there's not even need to change `PS1`, as the `connmanctl>` line could simply be obtained by `echo -n "connmanctl> "`.

The reason behind this curiosity is that I'm trying to write a wrapper to `connmanctl`. I've already written it, and it works as intended, except that I don't know how to properly setup the autocompletion feature, and I think that in order to do so I first need to understand what is the right way to write an interactive shell script.

Comment: When you start `connmanctl` without arguments in an interactive terminal, `connmanctl` reads its commands from the terminal. It is running, not `bash`. When you run it with arguments, it interprets a single command using its command line arguments, and then returns to bash.

Comment: Ok, @rici, this is exactly what I meant when I wrote _`connmanctl` is running all the time the prompt is `connmanctl>`_. Thank you for confirming this.